# copymethod() with Java string

Tags: java

I have a requirement to use copymethod() of unsafe class to use for a string, I came across the link http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/, where I found the following example-

```
String password = new String("l00k@myHor$e");
String fake = new String(password.replaceAll(".", "?"));
System.out.println(password); // l00k@myHor$e
System.out.println(fake); // ????????????
getUnsafe().copyMemory(
          fake, 0L, null, toAddress(password), sizeOf(password));

System.out.println(password); // ????????????
System.out.println(fake); // ????????????

static long toAddress(Object obj) {
    Object[] array = new Object[] {obj};
    long baseOffset = getUnsafe().arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);
    return normalize(getUnsafe().getInt(array, baseOffset));
}

private static long normalize(int value) {
    if(value >= 0) return value;
    return (~0L >>> 32) & value;
}
```

I tried the example but I got IllegalArgumentException. Can anyone please help in getting this example worked.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

My advice: **Don't do this!**

If you need to erase a String, you can do it "safely" by using reflection to dig out the String object's private `chars` array and filling it with NUL characters.  Of course, you need to be sure that the string you are erasing is not shared with other code; e.g. it has not been interned.

The code you are copying looks broken.  For a start, it seems to be assuming that references fit in an `int` ... which is not so for a 64 bit JVM.  I wouldn't trust that code.  I wouldn't even try to fix it.  This is simply the wrong approach.

Unsafe should only be used by people who really, really know what they are doing.  Copying someone else's code is not a substitute for knowledge.

And in this case, I don't think that the original code erased the characters properly.  In fact, I think it merely dismantles the `String` object, leaving the `char[]` containing the super-secret password intact in the heap.  The blog post actually hints at this.

---

In fact, it is next to impossible to guarantee that you have erased a String.  Even if you succeed in erasing the `char[]` containing the characters, you can't be sure that is the only copy of the data.  For instance, if the string has been relocated by the GC, there could still be an old copy of the characters in memory at the original location.  The characters will eventually be overwritten but there are no guarantees on when that will happen.

Probably the best you can do is to use JNI / JNA (or `Unsafe`) to allocate some off-heap (that won't be relocated by the GC) and over-write it with zeros before you release it.  Obviously, you can't do this with a String.

And even then ... there could be some stale pages on the paging device containing the characters.  Or someone with sufficient privilege could set a breakpoint and read the secret out of memory.

My advice: just make sure that the >>platform<< is properly secured, both physically and from access over the network.